# Manga where terminally ill girl becomes aware she's in a story

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember the story has a girl in high school who's terminally ill. She realizes she is a side character in a story. There's a mysterious guy who is like a 'cafeteria person', but only when they serve squid?

She ends up falling in love with a no name person and they try and enjoy the time they have in the story as it progresses. She ends up dying from her illness. But they get reused as characters in a different story and meet up again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi StackExchange, don't forget to check out the [tour] and [help]. Do you remember any details where/when you read this? When you do, please [edit] in those details!

Answer (score 4):

This is [How I Found It in July](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=146717).

[image: Cover image]

> What would you do if you found out that you were in fact a character in a comic? And an extra character on top of that? Change the course of the story, obviously!

The main character, Eun Danoh, discovers that she's a minor side character in a comic, fated to die. She's terminally ill with a heart condition, and abruptly starts experience memory issues - both suddenly appearing in places with lost time and no recollection of how she got there, and also knowledge of future events. She is told by a male cafeteria worker (who only appears when dried squid is on the menu) that they aren't human, and are just characters that appear in a comic - her memory loss is just the comic skipping ahead in time.

I haven't read the whole thing so I can't confirm the ending, but the early chapters are a perfect fit.